# Failing to load json in d3.js when using webpack

Tags: d3.js, webpack-dev-server

I followed this tutorial in order to use D3 with Webpack [How to Set Up D3.js with Webpack](https://code.likeagirl.io/how-to-set-up-d3-js-with-webpack-and-babel-7bd3f5e20df7)

But when I was trying to load my json with this code:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'

d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

I got this error message after I use the webpack web dev server:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) :8080/data.json
```

This is my webpack config

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './src/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})
module.exports = { 
  entry: './src/index.js', 
  output: { 
    path: path.resolve('dist'), 
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  }, 
  module: { 
    loaders: [ 
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
    ]
  }, 
  plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
}
```

And my package.json

```
{
  "name": "tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "babel src -d lib",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.3"
  }
}
```

Directory structure

```
Tutorial
  node_modules
  src
    data.json
    index.html
    index.js
  .babelrc
  package.json
  webpack.config.js
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: you don't event have `d3` as your dependencies

Comment: I guess it's because in the tutorial is not required to use `--save` when installing D3.js. But I could replicate the tutorial without problems.

Comment: Post your directory structure

Comment: I added my directory structure

Comment: Your error only says fail to load resource, which file does it fail to download? data.json? So after webpack finishes processing your build, your `index.html` will end up in `dist` directory which does not contain `data.json` hence `404`

Comment: yes, data.json fails

Comment: You need to tell webpack to copy `data.json` to `dist` too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141744/discussion-between-javier-cardenas-and-dummy).